# Java ADF "showPrintablePageBehavior"

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I currently have many rows on a table that load as a user scrolls down the page.
There is a `showPrintablePageBehavior` tag added to create a printable layout page upon clicking that will show the contents on the table. Currently, it only shows 25 or so rows at a time.
I am trying to figure out how to display every row on the new page once the button is clicked.

Is there anything I can add to the `<af:showPrintablePageBehavior/>` tag or the `af:commandToolbarButton` tag that could help transfer all the rows over? I know `fetchSize` may be an option, but I'm not sure how to implement that in.

Thank you!

Comment: Using JDeveloper 12C

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the showPrintablePageBehavior will not trigger a server go around. This means that you need to build another page where you fetch all data (set the fetchsize to -1) and print this. This blog https://myadfnotebook.blogspot.com/2011/01/adf-printable-pages-fetching-more-data.html shows how to do this.